# How do I authenticate Firebase functions/admin requests to Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I was able to complete the process of generating a Firebase auth token on the front end, sending it to a Firebase Cloud Function, and using auth.verifyIdToken to decode it and pull out the user ID.

I want to use Cloud Firestore, but I have no idea how to use the user token/ID when making requests to Cloud Firestore from Firebase Functions. My goal is to then have those variables available when creating Cloud Firestore security rules.

a) Do I need to pass those variables in the Firestore request?

Example:

```
postsRef.where({uid //somehow?}, 'published', '==', true).get();
```

b) Should I use `auth.setCustomUserClaims?` Is that the only option when working from the Admin SDK?

c) What is different in usage between the ID and the decoded token? Should I pass both to Cloud Firestore? Is that even possible?

Let me know what you think, any info is helpful.

Thanks,

Comment: Hi @CaineNielsen, if you think the below answer is helpful, please consider upvoting and marking it as accepted. Otherwise, feel free to ask any additional questions as far as your original question is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is actually not possible.  When you query Firestore from backend code using one of the server SDKs (including the Firebase Admin SDK), the query will always bypass all security rules.  There is no way to change this behavior.  Rules only apply to direct access from web and mobile clients.

What you'll have to do instead is duplicate the work of the rule in your backend code to make sure all the conditions are correct before making your query.